# Android App Crash due to dlopen("/libstlport_shared.so) failed: No such file or directory

Tags: android

My application is getting crashed at launch . I am getting following issue :

> D/dalvikvm( 6068): Trying to load lib *****/libstlport_shared.so
>
> E/( 6068): open file *****/libstlport_shared.so failed: No such file
>   or directory
>
> E/dalvikvm( 6068): dlopen("****/libstlport_shared.so") failed: dlopen
>   failed: library "*****/libstlport_shared.so" not found**

I am getting this issue with **ASUS_TOOG (Android 4.4.2)** . This is an x86 device. The issue is not reproducible on other x86 devices, this device only . Please do let me know if you have come across similar issue and fixed that before.

**Note**: I have recently moved my application compiler from gcc to clang ,could that be an issue?

Comment: are you using any 3rd party library in your app?

Comment: yes my application is using some third party libraries also

Comment: Levon,do you have idea about it, what can be the issue here?